# Get new rows from textarea with v-model - VueJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a concern how to get the string from textarea but also to get every new row added by pressing enter, also TAB space. Priority is to get every new row, so I can use that string to add to paragraphs but to respect new rows, TAB spaces.

Example:

Textarea text: http://prntscr.com/kvbbcv.

When I add value to the paragraph: 
http://prntscr.com/kvbbur

One more example: http://prntscr.com/kvhmca

What would be the best practice to fix this problem?

Code:

```
<textarea v-model="comment"></textarea>

<p>{{ comment }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to resolve this problem.

The solution is to use `<div contenteditable></div>` and get the value from this `<div>` when content inside of it is changed using `@input="contentEditableChange()"`

The function will return the value as HTML. But using `v-html` you can convert html string to html preview.

So final solution code is:

```
<div id="unique-element" @input="contentEditableChange()" contenteditable></div>

<p v-html="message"></p>
```

Method:

```
contentEditableChange() {
   this.message = document.getElementById("unique-element").innerHTML;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if you using ckeditor, you can try like this

```
<ckeditor v-model="comment"></ckeditor>    
<p v-html>{{comment}}</p>
```

because ckeditor has added new lines automatically. or if you use textarea,  add a `<br>` tag manually.